# Is it possible to create an animated gears user interface using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-interface

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a UI that has 2 gears that the user can control (through a button click or other event).

For example, the user clicks the "Advance 1" button, and the gears advance.

I'd like to do the project in .NET, but I also have limited experience in developing Android applications, and would be willing to do the research necessary if somebody could point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly what you're looking for -- but you could always write the UI in HTML/Javascript/Angular and launch the GUI with a Webview for the local files.